# Serialize ASPX page?

Tags: c#, asp.net, session, serialization

I am in the sitaution where I need to use an external session state server, which requires all my sessions to be serialized. I have been trying to make all the classes I store in sessions serializable, by using the `[Serializeable()]` attribute.

However, I keep getting the following error:

> Unable to serialize the session state.

In `StateServer` and `SQLServer` mode, ASP.NET will serialize the session state objects, and as a result non-serializable objects or `MarshalByRef` objects are not permitted. The same restriction applies if similar serialization is done by the custom session state store in '`Custom`' mode.

More interesting is however the stack trace:

> [SerializationException: Type 'ASP.useroverview_aspx' in Assembly 'App_Web_pwonykbc, Version=0.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' is not marked as serializable.]
>
> System.Runtime.Serialization.FormatterServices.InternalGetSerializableMembers(RuntimeType type) +9452985
>      System.Runtime.Serialization.FormatterServices.GetSerializableMembers(Type type, StreamingContext context) +247
>      System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.WriteObjectInfo.InitMemberInfo() +160
>      System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.WriteObjectInfo.InitSerialize(Object obj, ISurrogateSelector surrogateSelector, StreamingContext context, SerObjectInfoInit serObjectInfoInit, IFormatterConverter converter, ObjectWriter objectWriter, SerializationBinder binder) +218
>      System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.ObjectWriter.Write(WriteObjectInfo objectInfo, NameInfo memberNameInfo, NameInfo typeNameInfo) +388
>      System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.ObjectWriter.Serialize(Object graph, Header[] inHeaders, __BinaryWriter serWriter, Boolean fCheck) +444
>      System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.BinaryFormatter.Serialize(Stream serializationStream, Object graph, Header[] headers, Boolean fCheck) +133
>      System.Web.Util.AltSerialization.WriteValueToStream(Object value, BinaryWriter writer) +1708

The Type `ASP.useroverview_aspx` is as far as I know an ASPX page. The page I load is `Useroverview.aspx`. However, I don't try to store this page in a session. So this error makes me wonder quite a lot.

I tried to do the following in the code-behind:

```
[Serializable()]
public partial class UserOverview : Page
{
    private static readonly int TimerInterval = HttpContext.Current.IsDebuggingEnabled ? 2000 : 750;
    // ...
}
```

This did not help at all!

So I wonder if one could serialize an ASPX page? This don't know if this would make sense. I doubt it!

Thanks...

Comment: Why are you trying to store your page class in a Session? Something doesn;t sound right.

Comment: It sure looks like you have stored an instance of that page in the session. Do a quick search in your solution for `Session` and see if you can find the culprit.

Comment: I suspect that one of the objects in Session state has a reference to the page.

Comment: Thanks all.. I just tried searching my whole solution, and there is nowhere I store the page directly. Also, I could not see anywhere an object should have a reference..
Urh!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found the answer.. And you guys were right: One of my objects had a reference to the page.

I had an object Player, which had a list of events. One of these events had the current page as a target, which let to the problem.

I gave the event the following non serializable attribute:

```
[field: NonSerialized]
```

Then everything worked fine. And they all lived happily ever after!